# how to acomplish a full series in sql

Tags: sql-server

I want to achieve a full numeric scale from 0 to the max number in the table.

Let's say we have a table T with two fields named x and y

```
select x,y
from t
```

would show us lets say the results

```
X Y
3 11
5 23
7 45
9 1 
10 34
```

I found this query to build sequential numbers:

```
With T_Misparim As

(Select 1 N
Union All
Select  N+1 N
From    T_Misparim
Where   N<1000)
Select  N
From    T_Misparim
Option (MaxRecursion 0);
```

from this source : http://www.sqlserver.co.il/?p=3296

My bottom line is, how do i integrate the two queries into a single query to give 
right outer join  :

```
N X    Y
0 null 0
1 null 0
2 null 0
3 3    11
4 null 0
5 5    23
6 null 0
7 7    45
8 null 0
9 9    1
10 10  34
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just `LEFT JOIN` with the ordinal number CTE;

```
select 3 as X, 11 as Y into #TEST
insert #TEST values (5,23),(7,45),(9,1),(10,34)

;with NUMS(n) as (
    select 0 union all
    select 1 + n from NUMS where n < 50
)
select
    NUMS.n N,
    T.X,
    isnull(T.Y, 0) Y
from NUMS
    left join #TEST T on (T.X = NUMS.n)
option (maxrecursion 50)
```

For

```
N   X   Y
0   NULL    0
1   NULL    0
2   NULL    0
3   3   11
4   NULL    0
5   5   23
6   NULL    0
7   7   45
8   NULL    0
9   9   1
10  10  34
```